# Pandas groupby sum if value in group

Tags: python, pandas

Sample of data, actual data has many years. The type "Lien" or "Lien Endorsement" can only appear once per year. Other types can repeat within a year.

tax_allyears =

```
tax_year    type                amount  
2013        Lien Interest       4
2014        Lien Interest       10
2014        Lien                100
2014        Lien Interest       15
2013        Lien Endorsement    200
```

This line almost works, it sums the "Lien Interest" values by year.

```
by_year_interest = tax_allyears_1[tax_allyears_1['type'] == 'Lien Interest'].groupby(by=['tax_year'])['amount'].sum()
```

What I want is to distinguish between years that have "Lien" vs "Lien Interest"

by_year_Lien_interest = some function

```
tax_year    amount
2014        25
```

by_year_Lien_Endorsement_interest = some function

```
tax_year    amount
2013        4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create two different list of unique years, one where `Lien` comes, and the other where `Lien Endorsement` comes. And then use those unique lists in your condition for filtering the `tax_allyears` DataFrame using [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) . Example -

```
lienyears = tax_allyears.loc[tax_allyears['type'] == 'Lien','tax_year'].unique().tolist()
lienendorsementyears = tax_allyears.loc[tax_allyears['type'] == 'Lien Endorsement','tax_year'].unique().tolist()

by_year_lien_interest = tax_allyears[(tax_allyears['type'] == 'Lien Interest') & tax_allyears['tax_year'].isin(lienyears)].groupby('tax_year')['amount'].sum()
by_year_lien_endorsement_interest = tax_allyears[(tax_allyears['type'] == 'Lien Interest') & tax_allyears['tax_year'].isin(lienendorsementyears)].groupby('tax_year')['amount'].sum()
```

Demo -

```
In [7]: tax_allyears
Out[7]:
   tax_year              type  amount
0      2013     Lien Interest       4
1      2014     Lien Interest      10
2      2014              Lien     100
3      2014     Lien Interest      15
4      2013  Lien Endorsement     200

In [9]: lienyears = tax_allyears.loc[tax_allyears['type'] == 'Lien','tax_year'].unique().tolist()

In [10]: lienendorsementyears = tax_allyears.loc[tax_allyears['type'] == 'Lien Endorsement','tax_year'].unique().tolist()

In [13]: by_year_lien_interest = tax_allyears[(tax_allyears['type'] == 'Lien Interest') & tax_allyears['tax_year'].isin(lienyears)].groupby('tax_year')['amount'].sum()

In [15]: by_year_lien_endorsement_interest = tax_allyears[(tax_allyears['type'] == 'Lien Interest') & tax_allyears['tax_year'].isin(lienendorsementyears)].groupby('tax_year')['amount'].sum()

In [16]: by_year_lien_interest
Out[16]:
tax_year
2014    25
Name: amount, dtype: int64

In [17]: by_year_lien_endorsement_interest
Out[17]:
tax_year
2013    4
Name: amount, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I over simplified the problem, there is also a Parcel_Id column which needs to be included in the initial lists. That said I think I can figure it out now. Ill work on it a bit and update the question and allow you to update the answer if you want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `tax_year`, `type` and `amount` are the names of the `columns` in a `DataFrame`, then you can do this:

```
# Create a groupby object
name = df.groupby(['tax_year', 'type'])

# Apply the sum function to the groupby object
df = name.sum()
```